# jQuery fade image loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a loop in my function so that the slideshow effect always restarts.

Here's my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Be67B/

It's all good for the image 1 to go to image 2, but I want it to fade it back to the image 1, and then go the image 2, and so on...to always loop like that.

What do I need to add in my code to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this jquery cycle plugin:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

may be this is what you want

Comment: What a great plugin...so simple! Thank you. It does what I need but with almost no line of codes.

Comment: @user1388136 - Why load a whole plugin when you can accomplish this in a few lines of code?

Comment: @j08691 that is a standard and maintained plugin and with this you can accomplish many more task

Comment: @ParitoshSingh - I'm not questioning the plugin, I'm questioning the reason for using it and bloating the overall code when it's not needed. Plus the OP doesn't mention anything about needing the other features the plugin provides.

Comment: Why use plugins for everithing? I made the code for this in 30 seconds... this really require a plugin? another file?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a loop, just ask the browser to repetitively call your animation step :

```
setInterval(function(){
   // your animation (in fact just a step)
}, someDelay);
```

Demonstration : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/nPh6S/

In this precise case, the animation is done with :

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("#top").fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).attr("src","http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-cFt5KNrHsHc/TZMH6XUBu-I/AAAAAAAAAR4/R6hOP7lffx0/s1600/apple-logo.png").fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).attr('src', 'http://coreldrawtips.com/images/applebig.jpg').fadeIn().delay(1000);
        });
     }
    );
}, 4000);
```

Comment: It works but it always fades to the same image...? I need it to go back to the first image

Comment: I updated (http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/nPh6S/). I think this is more what you're looking for ? You'd still have to tune for the exact desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that does the transition, which has a callback function as part of the `fadeIn` method that will call back to itself to trigger the next transition, and it would just be in a constant loop.

Here's your modified jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Be67B/1/

**HTML:**

```
<img id="top" src="http://coreldrawtips.com/images/applebig.jpg" width="300" height="300" />​
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  transition(false);
});

function transition(first)
{
    var src = first ? "http://coreldrawtips.com/images/applebig.jpg" : "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-cFt5KNrHsHc/TZMH6XUBu-I/AAAAAAAAAR4/R6hOP7lffx0/s1600/apple-logo.png";

    $("#top").delay(1000).fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).attr("src",src).fadeIn(function() {
            transition(!first);
        });
    });    
}
    ​
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // images in the pool
   var images=["http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-cFt5KNrHsHc/TZMH6XUBu-     I/AAAAAAAAAR4/R6hOP7lffx0/s1600/apple-logo.png",
           "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-cFt5KNrHsHc/TZMH6XUBu-I/AAAAAAAAAR4/R6hOP7lffx0/s1600/apple-logo.png"];

      // next image to display
      var next = 0;

      // interval beetween images
      var INTERVAL = 1000;

      // main function
      var doCarrousel = function() {
         $("#top").fadeOut(function() {
             $(this).attr("src", images[next]).fadeIn(
                 function() {
                   setTimeout(doCarrousel, INTERVAL);
                 });
          });
          if (++next >= images.length)
             next = 0;
       };

       //start carrousel
       doCarrousel();
});
```

**fiddler**: http://jsfiddle.net/Be67B/

Answer (score 0):

I would use a plugin. But you can do it by hand. I just recommend against changing the src of the images, because some browsers don't handle it very well, like safari not firing load event.

Instead, have all images inside a container, and cycle their visibility:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentImage = $("#images img:first");

    setInterval(function(){
        currentImage.fadeOut();

        if(currentImage.next().size())
            currentImage = currentImage.next();
        else
            currentImage = currentImage.siblings().first();

        currentImage.fadeIn();
    }, 1000)
});
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Be67B/2/

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Be67B/3/)**

```
function swap(img) {
    img = (img == 'http://coreldrawtips.com/images/applebig.jpg') ? 'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-cFt5KNrHsHc/TZMH6XUBu-I/AAAAAAAAAR4/R6hOP7lffx0/s1600/apple-logo.png' : 'http://coreldrawtips.com/images/applebig.jpg';
    $('#top').delay(2000).fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).attr('src', img)
    }).fadeIn(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            swap(img)
        }, 1000);
    });
};
swap($('#top').attr('src'));​
```